# ObservableCollection отследить новые и измененные елементы

Tags: c#, wpf

Как отследить елементы ObservableCollection который забинден к DataGridView которые изменились или добавились?

Comment: [ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: Что значит "изменились"? Сами объекты остались прежними, но изменились некоторые их свойства? Если так, что сам объект должен оповещать об этом реализуя INPC

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, именно

Comment: Если именно отловить, то [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818985/220553). Если просто обновить данные во View, то реализуйте INPC!