# Как запретить изменение индекса в TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, вкладки, tabcontrol

Я хотела реализовать закрытие нефокусированной вкладки TabControl в приложении WPF C#.

При создании вкладки кнопке закрытия в заголовке этой вкладки присваивается индекс, но дело в том, что при удалении вкладки, например посередине, порядок следования индексов самих вкладок меняется. Тем самым тэг кнопки не будет совпадать с индексом этой вкладки.

Чтобы было понятнее, пример:
Тэг кнопки |0 1 2 3 4 5
Индекс вкл|0 1 2 3 4 5

Закрываем, например, третью вкладку:

Тэг кнопки |0 1 2 4 5
Индекс вкл|0 1 2 3 4

Получается несоответствие. Какие-то формулы выводить бесполезно.

Вот код:

```
        public void New_TabControl(string n, Page p)
    {

        TabItem ti = new TabItem();
        DockPanel dp = new DockPanel();
        Label l = new Label();
        Button b = new Button();
        Frame f = new Frame();

        ti.MaxHeight = 50;
        ti.MaxWidth = 150;

        l.Content = n;
        l.MaxWidth = 100;

        b.Content = "x";
        b.Width = 30;
        b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Close_Tab);

        ti.Header = dp;

        ti.Content = f;
        f.Content = p;

        dp.Children.Add(l);
        dp.Children.Add(b);

        TB.Items.Add(ti);
        ti.Focus();
        b.Tag = this.TB.SelectedIndex;
    }

    public void Close_Tab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        MessageBox.Show(b.Tag.ToString() + TB.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        TB.Items.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(b.Tag));
    }
```

Возможно ли запретить изменение индекса у вкладки? Как правильно это реализовать? Или нужно будет делать что-то наподобие таблицы, хранящей текущие вкладки и метку фокуса?

Comment: Мне интересно, а почему вы написали такое? Это ваш первый проект или что? Вы ведь делаете уйму косяков! 1. Ваши контролы содержат данные, которые им не предназначены. 2. Вы работаете с контролами через код. Это уместно может быть в WinForms, но не в WPF! 3. Вы совсем не используете основной аспект WPF - привязки. 4. Вы используете Frame, который давно уже пора выкинуть на помойку, ибо это как сейчас использовать internet explorer какой нибудь древней версии для просмотра любимого сайта. Хотите нормальное приложение? Выкиньте все написанное вам и перепишите по правилам MVVM!

Comment: Я бы и рада, но это моя вторая программа на c# с wpf и вообще второе десктопное приложение. Пока что я в этом не сильна. А быстрой информации по этому поводу (паттерн MVVM и т.п.) я уж точно не смогу получить. Очень мало тех, кто с нуля учит сразу правильно.

Comment: Да ладно, не уж то нет нормальной информации по этому всему? Я например [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553) подобное, не уж то непонятно и долго надо учить? Я соглашусь, да, и сам писал нечто подобное изначально, пока меня не поставили на правильный путь. Хорошо, если я вам напишу простенький пример вкладок с удалением по правилам MVVM, вам даст это хоть что-то? Или и дальше будете писать не правильно?

Comment: Я всего (или уже много) 4 месяца с этим знакома. До этого только колледжный уровень c++. Мне бы нормальную литературу по этому поводу. Я, конечно, нашла книгу МакДональда, но пока что остановилась на ~160 стр. Если далее правильный подход к написанию приложений будет описан в ней далее, то я думаю, что ваш пример мне поможет. Потому что в интернете нет примеров реализации таких вкладок. Я нашла только этот подход, который и написала в коде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Это вряд ли ответит на ваш вопрос, ибо я показываю то, как это должно быть и в каком направление вам стоит следовать.</sup>

И так, для начала давайте взглянем на ваш код и выпишем ряд проблемных мест:

1. Вы храните в контролах данные, о которых им знать совсем не обязательно. Контролы - это View, то есть то, что взаимодействует с клиентом. Что им надо знать для успешной работы? Ну, наверно цвет, размер, положение, стиль и все, что связано с отображением. Все, остальное вы не должны хранить в контролах. К примеру вы в `Tag` храните индекс, зачем это знать контролу?
2. Вы работаете с контролами через код. Это в каком то смысли допустимо, но вы тем самым делаете много лишней работы, которая не должна вас беспокоить. Вот представьте, что у вас нет интерфейса вовсе, или через некоторое время вы решили переписать ваш проект и сделать из него к примеру консольное приложение, что тогда? Будете делать новый проект, копировать туда логику, переписывать ее для работы с консолью? А что, если мы эту логику изначально отвяжем от интерфейса, сделаем универсальной, то нам бы не пришлось переписывать проект, ведь достаточно было бы подключить новый интерфейс и все.
3. `Frame` - Он имеет в себе много лишнего и не позволяет сделать многое. Попробуйте например изменить контент основного фрейма через дочерний фрейм. У вас это может и получится, но с большим трудом.

Исходя из этого, я вам очень сильно советую начать разрабатывать проект хотя бы с использованием привязок, ибо это основное "оружие" WPF и без них, ваш проект теряет многое, включая скорость в работе.

---

Теперь давайте напишем небольшой проект по правилам MVVM, который будет иметь следующее:

- Основную страницу с вкладками.
- Возможность закрывать вкладки.
- Возможность задать контент нужной вкладки.

**Первым делом определимся, что такое MVVM:**
В двух словах, это некий подход, который разделяет ваш код на некие слои, где каждый слой отвечает на что-то одно:

- **Model** - Источник данных. Допустим у вас есть сайт, который имеет API методы для взаимодействия с его данными. Вот работа с этим API, получение данных, отправка данных, это все и будет Model.
- **View** - Это пользовательский интерфейс. Этот слой отвечает только за отображение. Также хочу заметить, что данный слой не должен знать совершенно нечего о других слоях.
- **ViewModel** - некий связующий слой, который формирует данные для отображения. К примеру Model слой содержит в себе имя человека, его id и возраст. Зачем нам отдавать пользователю ID, если это по сути внутренняя информация (как пример)? Вот мы и делаем ViewModel пользователя, только с его именем и возрастом, делаем методы, которые помогут нам это отобразить правильно и все, остальная логика в Model слое.

**Теперь мы можем начать разрабатывать проект:**

- Создадим для удобства папку `ViewModel`
- В созданной папке сделаем класс `MainViewModel` - это будет наш основной класс, к которому мы привяжем View слой.
- Далее заходим в `App.xaml` и удаляем там строчку `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`
- Заходим в `App.xaml.cs` и переопределяем метод `OnStartup`, в котором инициализируем `MainViewModel` и нужное нам окно:

  ```
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainViewModel() }.Show();
  }
  ```

  <sup>Вы спросите "А зачем это?" и на этот вопрос я оставлю вам [эту ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586).</sup>
- Создадим класс `TabViewModel` - это будет ViewModel одной вкладки.
- В этом классе сделаем необходимые свойства (помним, что привязка возможна только к публичным свойствам!). Что нам надо? Заголовок вкладки и наверно ее контент, также для удобства переопределим конструктор:

  ```
  class TabViewModel
  {
      public TabViewModel(string title, object content = default)
          => (Title, Content) = (title, content);

      public string Title { get; set; }
      public object Content { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Теперь нам надо в главной VM сделать коллекцию этих вкладок. Тут стоит сразу подумать, а будут ли у нас обновляться вкладки в будущем? Если да, то нам нужна коллекция, которая имеет реализованный интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`, без него вы не будете видеть изменения в View слое. Из готовых решений есть `ObservableCollection<T>` или `BindingList<T>`. Если изменения не важны, то можете использовать что угодно.

  ```
  class MainViewModel
  {
      public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>
      {
          new TabViewModel("Вкладка 1"),
          new TabViewModel("Вкладка 2"),
          new TabViewModel("Вкладка 3")
      };
  }
  ```
- Ну и остается нам это все привязать. Делаем нужный вид вкладок и привязываем их к коллекции:

  ```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  </TabControl>
  ```

Все, запускаем проект и видим там 3 вкладки из коллекции с пустым контентом:

[image: Result1]

Заметьте, весь код формирования вкладок успешно может работать без интерфейса, мы не используем фрейм и мы разместили все по своим местам.

**Теперь давайте отобразим во вкладках разное содержимое:**
<sup>Делать будем по [данному примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122).</sup>

- Создадим в директории `ViewModel` новый класс, назовем его к примеру `FirstPageViewModel`, данный класс пусть содержит всего 1 свойство, его текст:

  ```
  class FirstPageViewModel
  {
      public string Text { get; } = "Первая страница";
  }
  ```
- Далее создадим новую директорию, которую назовем `View`.
- В эту директорию мы добавим новый "Пользовательский элемент управления", который назовем просто, `FirstPage`. Этой странице задаем нужный дизайн и я также отображу текст, который содержится в VM слое:

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.Background>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="Gainsboro" Offset="1"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Grid.Background>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                 FontSize="30"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>
  ```
- Теперь нам надо это все объединить, сделаем это в главном окне:

  - Добавляем в самом верху ссылки на VM и V директории (namespace'ы тут должны быть ваши, даю как пример того, что должно быть):

    ```
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPFApp.ViewModel"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:WPFApp.View"
    ```
  - Чуть дописываем `TabControl`, добавляя ему ресурсы (они по сути могут быть где угодно, но если нам эти страницы нужны только для этого контрола, то задаем ресурсы ему):

    ```
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstPageViewModel}">
            <v:FirstPage/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    ```

    Тут все просто, мы при помощи `DataType` указываем тип объекта и внутри `DataTemplate` задаем нужный вид для указанного типа.
- Ну и теперь зададим например первой вкладке нужный контент (помним, что мы классу `TabViewModel` сделали свойство с контентом):

  ```
  new TabViewModel("Вкладка 1", new FirstPageViewModel()),
  ```

Запускаем и видим, что первая вкладка изменила свой вид:

[image: Result2]

Таким образом мы имеем приложение с вкладками, где каждая вкладка может иметь свой контент, без фрейма!

**Ну и последнее, закрытие вкладки:**

Что такое закрытие? Это по сути удаление из списка объекта. Но как нам удалить объект из коллекции, если мы не можем по правилам MVVM подписываться на события кнопки и обращаться к контролам? А все просто, тут на помощь приходят события и команды!

- Создадим класс, который реализует нам интерфейс `ICommand`. Данных реализаций в интернете полно, я возьму эту, ибо нам достаточно только обработать удобно команду, не более:

  ```
  public class RelayCommand : ICommand
  {
      private Action action;
      public RelayCommand(Action action) => this.action = action;
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
      #pragma warning disable CS0067
      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
      #pragma warning restore CS0067
      public void Execute(object parameter) => action();
  }
  ```
- Добавим в `TabViewModel` новую команду, которая будет оповещать всех подписчиков о том, что вкладка закрывается:

  ```
  class TabViewModel
  {
      public TabViewModel(string title, object content = default)
      {
          (Title, Content) = (title, content);
          CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(Close);
      }

      public event Action<TabViewModel> OnClose;
      public ICommand CloseCommand { get; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public object Content { get; set; }
      void Close() => OnClose?.Invoke(this);
  }
  ```

  Тут смотрите что происходит. При клике на некую кнопку (о ней далее), которая будет привязана к `CloseCommand` будет вызываться метод `Close()`, этот метод в свою очередь оповещает всех подписчиков на событие `OnClose` о том, что данная вкладка нуждается в закрытие.
- Теперь у нас есть два пути. 1. Это при инициализации `TabViewModel` самим делать подписку. 2. Мы можем это немного автоматизировать. Давайте сделаем 2-е. Чуть перепишем `MainViewModel` (а точнее инициализацию коллекции вкладок):

  ```
  class MainViewModel
  {
      public MainViewModel()
      {

          Tabs.CollectionChanged += OnTabsChanged;
          Tabs.Add(new TabViewModel("Вкладка 1", new FirstPageViewModel()));
          Tabs.Add(new TabViewModel("Вкладка 2"));
          Tabs.Add(new TabViewModel("Вкладка 3"));
      }

      public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();

      private void OnTabsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.OldItems != null)
          {
              foreach (TabViewModel item in e.OldItems)
                  item.OnClose -= CloseTab;
          }
          if (e.NewItems != null)
          {
              foreach (TabViewModel item in e.NewItems)
                  item.OnClose += CloseTab;
          }
      }

      void CloseTab(TabViewModel tab) => Tabs.Remove(tab);
  }
  ```

  Тут мы перенесли добавление вкладок в конструктор, а также добавили подписались на событие `CollectionChanged` этой коллекции. Данное событие происходит в тот момент, когда туда добавляется/удаляется что либо. При добавление новой вкладки, мы подписываемся на его событие закрытия, а при удаление наоборот, отписываемся.
  <sup>О данном подходе я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818985/220553).</sup>
- Осталось нам с вами сделать кнопку закрытия в View слое, дописываем ее в `TabControl.ItemTemplate`:

  ```
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
              <Button Content="x" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" 
                      Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                      Margin="3 -2 0 0"
                      Cursor="Hand"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  ```

  Тут основную роль играет `Command`, идет привязка к созданному свойству в `TabViewModel`.

Все, запускаем и радуемся результату:

[image: Result3]

**Пара дополнений:**

- Если ваше свойство может измениться во время работы приложения (например контент у вкладки), то не забудьте реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, ибо без него вы не получите изменений в интерфейсе.
- Если вам надо открыть программно нужную вкладку, то сделайте свойство (с INPC) рядом с коллекцией, которое будет содержать в себе текущий открытый `TabViewModel` и привяжите его к `TabControl` (прим: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemProperty}"`).
- MVVM - это некие правила, которые сделают ваш проект более продуктивным и удобным. Следовать этому подходу, решать вам.

В общем удачи в изучении C#!

Comment: Спасибо, за отличный урок по работе с табами.