# Как динамически создавать Template для кнопки в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Path path = new();
path.Data = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L8,8 M8,0 L0,8");
path.StrokeThickness = 3;

ControlTemplate controlTemplate = new() { Template = /*template*/ };

Button button = new() { Template = controlTemplate };
```

как мне создать Template на основе path (что вписать вместо `/*template*/`)?

Comment: Вы игнорируете самую важную часть WPF, а именно XAML! У вас не должно быть вообще работы с контролами в C# коде, ведь это ответственность именно XAML. Поэтому, я вам очень сильно советую научиться пользоваться привязками и XAML разметкой, ибо сейчас вы делаете дикий костыль, который повлияет на все аспекты проекта (от скорости, до удобства).

Comment: я знаю что в теории можно создать template в XAML и потом подвязать его через c# но опять же не нашел на эту тему ничего путного.

Comment: Где вы увидели `в XAML и потом подвязать его через c#` во фразе `У вас не должно быть вообще работы с контролами в C# коде`? Еще раз повторю, **у вас не должно быть в C# коде вообще создание контролов, стилей, кнопочек, всяких `myTextBox.Text = "Text";` и так далее**, этому попросту не место в C#, этому место в XAML.

Comment: А что делать если вся суть в динамическом создании объектов? Или этого можно избежать, тогда подскажите, пожалуйста, как? Скорее всего я упускаю какую-то важную особенность WPF.

Comment: Смотря, какая динамика. Если просто вывод данных из массива, то привязываете `ItemsControl` (или его производные `ListBox` и др.), делаете контролу нужный стиль, все, готово. Если динамика прям вообще динамика, а-ля "по координатам 100х30 кидаем кнопку", то тут зависит от того, как и что хотите, по сути также привязка `ItemsControl` к объекту с координатами.

Comment: У меня динамика открытия и закрытия вкладок в TabControl, при этом в заголовке каждой вкладки должна находиться кнопка закрытия вкладки. Может можно создать в XAML шаблон для этого и применять его ко всем вкладкам в приложении? Наверное это уже не особо связанно с изначальной темой.

Comment: А чем вкладки отличаются от кнопок в `ItemsControl`?) К примеру вот я [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090412/220553), полноценный пример динамичных вкладок, которые привязаны к простой коллекции, да еще и "крестик" закрытия имеют) Заметьте, ни единого контрола в C# коде.