# Как сделать TabControl в приложении WPF в стиле Firefox/Krnl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

[image: Krnl]

[image: Firefox]

Табы будут для переключения между страницами с Monaco

Comment: Вы определитесь, вам стиль, или функционал вкладок? Если стиль - то это простые прямоугольники, а если функционал, то [читайте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090412/220553).

Comment: как у крнл, фаерфокс для примера, простые вкладки без иконок, с закрытыем, открытыем в конце

Comment: Ну я вам дал выше ссылку того, как открывать вкладки, со своим содержимом, да еще и с крестиком закрытие. Берите, изучайте, дорабатывайте.

Comment: спасибо, полезно