# Как добавить родителя для WebBrowser в WPF C#

Tags: wpf, webbrowser

Обычным образом родитель задается таким способом, но в WPF произошла проблема с тем, что Parent имеет только get.

`WebBrowser webTab = new WebBrowser {Parent = tabpage};`

tabpage в данном случае элемент Tab Control

Все, спасибо решил. Если кто-то столкнется с такой проблемой, то стоит указать в создаваемой вкладке tabpage.content и туда всунуть браузер:

`tabpage.Content= webTab;`

Comment: Один вопрос - зачем? Другой вопрос - Зачем устаревший, заброшенный `WebBrowser`?

Comment: Такое уж задание дали. Нужно разместить браузер на программно-созданной вкладке

Comment: 1. Где вы увидели свойство `Parent` у браузера? Я вот открыл документацию по WinForms/WPF, вообще не нашел этого свойства. Говорите "обычным образом задается", а я вот впервые об этом слышу. Так родитель задается у окна, но не у контролов, да и то у окна это сделано больше для другого функционала, не того, который вы ожидаете. 2. С чего вы взяли, что указав родителя, браузер будет внутри вкладки? Ну и 3. В WPF проекте так не пишут код, в WPF принято использовать привязки и XAML, вот ваш браузер должен быть в XAML, а не создан через код, вот вам [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090412).