# Передача параметра из другой VM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В общем есть некоторый список:

```
    private ObservableCollection<SiteConfig> _sites;

    public ObservableCollection<SiteConfig> Sites
    {
        get => _sites;
        set => Set(ref _sites, value);
    }
```

Он находится в основной `MainWindnowVM` и привязан к одному `TabItem`. Также есть другой `TabItem` для регистрации нового элемента в списке сайтов, который находится в другой `NewSiteVM`. Проблема в том, что не знаю как передать данный список из `MainWindnowVM` в `NewSiteVM`, чтобы добавить новую запись при срабатывании команды.

`DataContext` объявил вот так, не знаю данное объявление нарушает принципы `MVVM`, но мне было так удобнее, нежеле в `XAML`

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AllSitesTabItem.DataContext = new MainWindnowVM();
        CreateNewPasswordTabItem.DataContext = new NewSiteVM();
    }
```

`AllSitesTabItem` и `CreateNewPasswordTabItem` - имена `TabItem`-ов.

Была идея сделать данный список статичным, но думаю это быдет лишь **костыль** и не знаю можно ли будет потом его связать с `DataGrid`.

Вся разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="PWManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PasswordsManager" Height="600" Width="800">
<Grid>

    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabItem}">
        <TabItem x:Name="AllSitesTabItem" Header="Мои пароли">
            <Grid>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.85*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          Margin="10" Padding="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sites}" 
                          IsReadOnly="True">
             
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Path=SiteUsl}" 
                                                 ContentBinding="{Binding Path=SiteName}">
                            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnHyperlinkClick"/>
                                </Style>    
                            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата регистрации" Binding="{Binding Path=RegisteDate}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                <TextBlock Text="Пароль: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SitePassword}" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Последнее изменение: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateLastChange}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                </DataGrid>

                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Создать новый пароль" 
                        Height="50" Margin="10" Command="{Binding Path=NewSiteClick}"/>
            </Grid>
            
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="CreateNewPasswordTabItem" Header="Новый пароль">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="Название Сайта" Margin="10, 20, 0, 15" FontSize="17"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Text="{Binding Path=SiteName}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="Пароль" Margin="10, 15, 0, 15" FontSize="17"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Text="{Binding Path=Password}"/>

                <TextBlock Text="Повторно пароль" Margin="10, 15, 0, 15" FontSize="17"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Text="{Binding Path=PasswordAgain}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="" Margin="10"/>

                <TextBlock Text="Ссылка на сайт" Margin="10, 15, 0, 15" FontSize="17"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10, 0, 10, 20" Text="{Binding Path=Uri}"/>

                <Button Content="Добавить" Margin="10" Height="50"
                    Command="{Binding Path=NewSiteClick}" />

            </StackPanel>

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: У вас нет MVVM вообще. Привязки, и чистый WPF, все. Ну а про вопрос - я вам уже говорил в предыдущем, вы сказали "я знаю", но видимо нет... Показываю: `class NewSiteVM { private readonly MainWindnowVM _mainVM; public NewSiteVM(MainWindnowVM mainVM) => _mainVM = mainVM; }` далее `... = NewSiteVM(this);`. Поздравляю, вы передали через конструктор ссылку одного класса на другой, теперь вы можете без труда в классе `NewSiteVM` получить доступ к объектам главного класса, например, `_mainVM.Sites`.

Comment: На счет вопроса понял и наконец смог, спасибо. На счет MVVM хотел дополнительно спросить. Я его учу по видео с ютуба и там так описывается вся структура, скорее всего плейлист плохой. Можете посоветовать статьи, курсы по теме MVVM чтобы далее не задавал такие нелепые вопросы

Comment: Советовать что либо не буду, лишь скажу - не смотрите русскоязычных ютуберов, увы и ах, говорят ересь. Зарубежные, без проблем, там много отличного контента, но у нас.. Единицы. Ну а так, поймите саму суть MVVM, зачем вообще этот подход, а затем просто следуйте ему.

Comment: Вот что такое MVVM? Это деление всего на мало связанные слои, где M слой не знает ничего про VM и V, а V не знает ничего про M и VM. Ключевое тут "мало связанные", ну а вы делаете например `AllSitesTabItem.DataContext = new MainWindnowVM();`, где окно (V слой) вдруг знает про VM и отвечает за него. Также `OnHyperlinkClick` - это должна быть команда, а значит сейчас у вас за логику отвечает View слой, когда должен отвечать VM, а еще лучше M. В общем, уберите все `x:Name` и пишите код так, чтоб UI был в одном месте, а логика в другом и их ничего не связывало, будет вам MVVM.

Comment: Вкладки помню писал однажды, почитайте [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090412/220553), думаю будет полезно.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам. По-настоящему хороший человек. Всего Вам хорошего

Comment: На будущее, не стесняйтесь спрашивать, не стесняйтесь узнавать, не стесняйтесь доводить до конца свои вопросы, не стесняйтесь в конце концов своих пробелов в познаниях, это нормально! Вот вы задали сейчас по сути дубликат своего предыдущего вопроса, когда могли там сразу сказать "извините, не знаю как передать через конструктор". Так что, удачи в обучении!

Comment: Имхо, но передавать VM в VM такое себе. Команду должна исполнять М? Первый раз слышу.

Comment: @OwDafuq Чтож плохого в передаче VM в VM? Такой трюк часто используется например в переключении страниц, где в главной VM у нас есть условный `PageVM CurrentPage {get; set;}`, а в нужных страницах делаем `mainVM.CurrentPage = ...;`. Да, если идти глубже, проект больше, то там уже пишется все по принципам IoC, используют контейнеры, делают сервисы, но чистый WPF проект, без всего этого, да еще и для обучения, почему и нет?

Comment: @OwDafuq `Команду должна исполнять М?` - Внимательно прочитайте что я написал, я говорил про логику, а не конкретно команду. Вот у нас в команде логика получения данных из базы, где ей место? В VM или всеж M? Я думаю должна быть своя M, которую мы вызываем в команде, которая находится в VM. Об этом я и писал выше. Так что, как по мне, ваш комментарий весьма странный...

Comment: 1) Переключение страниц через установку в какой-то VM... За это должен отвечать отдельный сервис, разве нет?
2) Логика получения данных - сервис/репозиторий/что угодно, но не модель данных точно, обычно отдается сервис в VM, который и отдает вам нужные М. В данном случае сервис/репозиторий/etc. не будет М, а будет просто зависимостью. 
3) Да, чистый WPF круто, конечно, но как только у вас появляется чуть больше чем 2-3 страницы и больше 1-2 сервисов в приложении, то это уже становится не удобно и не поддерживаемо, поэтому мой совет сразу в пару к WPF изучать и Prism.

Comment: И, если уж так хочется передать MainVM, чтобы управлять страницами, то ИМХО, но лучше организовать это в сервис, который будет принимать в себя только название страницы, а внутри уже будет устанавливать нужную страницу сам, за это не должна отвечать отдельно взятая страница как по мне. Тот же Prism такое и делает, когда для переключения страниц предоставляет только регион и сервис для переключения страниц.

Comment: @OwDafuq И опять-же вы полезли в дебри. Человек делает себе банальный "ТУДУ" для изучения, а вы ему призм, сервисы, и прочее... Вы путаете голый MVVM с MVVM + сервисы + контейнер. Я согласен, что с полноценном, здоровом проекте, логику контента лучше выносить в отдельный класс, но на простых проектах, это лишний гемор, лишний код, который только запутает. Ну а понять всякие призмы, когда будет знание об MVVM труда не составит. Ну, не мне тут конечно судить, автор пусть изучает все что хочет.

Comment: Опять же имхо, но пройдя весь этот путь - лучше бы я сразу изучал как правильно делать, контейнеры, Prism и прочее, а не делал бы проекты не пойми как)