# Проблема с ViewModel TabControl (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

Ломаю голову уже целую ночь и так не пришел к ответу;(
Надеюсь, что вы мне поможете
Приступим, имеется разметка (Фото приложил) для TabControl

Проблема в том, что при переходе на ViewModel возникли проблемы с табами, самый первый при запуске приложения отрабатывает нормально, а кнопки добавить и удалить табы не работают. Ранее было событие, которое добавляла, удаляла табы и их содержимое, а при переходе на View такого события нет.

```
private void MyTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Source is TabControl)
    {
    var pos = MyTabControl.SelectedIndex;
    if (pos != 0 && pos == Tabs.Count - 1) //last tab
    {
        var tab = Tabs.Last();
        ConvertPlusToNewTab(tab);
        AddNewPlusButton();
    }
    }
}
```

Я пытался как мог, но событие так и не удалось мне написать. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой код, может кто сможет подсказать как мне быть и что нужно сделать. Спасибо!

```
public class TabControlViewModel : ObservableRecipient{

    public TabControlViewModel()
{
    var tab1 = new TabVM()
    {
        Header = $"Новая вкладка",
        Content = new ContentVM(new Frame(), new CompletionPage()),
    };

    Tabs.Add(tab1);
    AddNewPlusButton();
}

private ObservableCollection<TabVM> tabs = new();

public ObservableCollection<TabVM> Tabs
{
    get => tabs;
    set => SetProperty(ref tabs, value);
}


private string? _header;
public string? Header
{
    get => _header;
    set => SetProperty(ref _header, value);
}

private int _tabSelectedItem;

public int TabSelectedItem
{
    get => _tabSelectedItem;
    set => SetProperty(ref _tabSelectedItem, value);
}

private int _tabSelectedIndex;
public int TabSelectedIndex
{
    get => _tabSelectedIndex;
    set => SetProperty(ref _tabSelectedIndex, value);
}

public void SelectionChanged()
{
    if (TabSelectedIndex != 0 && TabSelectedIndex == Tabs.Count - 1) //last tab
    {
        var tab = Tabs.Last();
        ConvertPlusToNewTab(tab);
        AddNewPlusButton();
    }
}
public ICommand MyTabControl_Button => new RelayCommand(OnTabCloseClick);


public void AddNewPlusButton()
{
    var plusTab = new TabVM()
    {
        Header = "+",
        IsPlaceholder = true
    };
    Tabs.Add(plusTab);
}




public void ConvertPlusToNewTab(TabVM tab)
{
    //Do things to make it a new tab.
    tab.Header = $"Новая вкладка";
    tab.IsPlaceholder = false;
    tab.Content = new ContentVM(new Frame(), new CompletionPage());
}

private void OnTabCloseClick()
{

    if (Tabs.Count > 1)
    {
        if (TabSelectedItem == Tabs.Count - 2)//last tab before [+]
        {
            TabSelectedIndex--;
        }
        Tabs.RemoveAt(TabSelectedItem);
    }
}

public class TabVM : ObservableRecipient
{
    string _header;
    public string Header
    {
        get => _header;
        set => SetProperty(ref _header, value);
    }

    bool _IsPlaceholder = false;
    public bool IsPlaceholder
    {
        get => _IsPlaceholder;
        set => SetProperty(ref _IsPlaceholder, value);
    }

    ContentVM _Content = null;
    public ContentVM Content
    {
        get => _Content;
        set => SetProperty(ref _Content, value);
    }
}

public class ContentVM
{
    public ContentVM(Frame frame, CompletionPage completionPage)
    {
        CompletionPage = completionPage;
        Frame = frame;
    }
    public CompletionPage CompletionPage { get; set; }
    public Frame Frame { get; set; }
}}
```

[image: Код XAML]

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь писать все по MVVM, то у вас его нет. MVVM - это разделение всего на 3 мало связанных друг с другом слоя, View - весь UI (шрифты, стили, картинки, и прочее), Model - слой данных (база, работа с сайтом, ссылки на картинку, и прочее), ViewModel - связующий слой, который общается с Model, подготавливает нужные свойства для привязки View слоя. View не должен **ничего** знать про VM и M, аналогично и Model - не должен знать про другие слои, ViewModel - не должна знать про View.

Comment: Теперь внимание на ваш код, у вас есть событие `MyTabControl_SelectionChanged` - это UI событие, которое вдруг вызывает VM методы `ConvertPlusToNewTab` и `AddNewPlusButton`, то есть у вас View **знает** про VM, а это не правильно, это нарушение. Ну а вообще, этот вопрос дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090412/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если View ничего не знает про VM, то как тогда делать привязку к данным? Если View ничего не знает про VM, то зачем тогда существует x:TypeArguments, который часто используется в ReactiveUI? Если View ничего не знает про Model, то как тогда сделать EnumToVisibilityConverter или использовать любой конвертер, ведь мы ничего не знаем про VM? Выходит View все же что-то знает)

Comment: @Lapish Привязки - V ничего не знает про VM, знает лишь название некого свойства, которое должно быть найдено, не более. C `x:Type` чуть сложнее, ибо повторю, V не должна ничего знать про другие слои, а значит нам нужна абстракция над VM, можно даже интерфейс, который уже и будет указан как тип. Ну а конвертор - вы не должны хотеть конвертировать в UI VM слой в что-то другое, ваша VM'ка должна дать конкретные данные, которые уже можно через конвертор перегонять, но не VM в конверторе. MVVM это про разделение всего на слои, чистый MVVM, это когда вы удалили все кроме V и проект запускается.

Comment: Простой пример, закрыть окно по кнопке, как решите? С нарушением MVVM будет передан объект окна в класс, где есть команда, и уже в команде будет обращение к V и вызов его закрытия. Как видим, мы нарушаем MVVM, ибо VM знает про V, они тесно связаны и не могут существовать без друг друга. Но мы можем их разделить, например, создав интерфейс с простым `Action Close()`, реализуем этот интерфейс у VM и вызываем там `Invoke()`, а в V (окно), проверяем например `DataContext` на соответствие этому интерфейсу и задаем `Action`, готово, как видите, классы отвязаны, знают лишь про интерфейс, вот вам MVVM

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня обычно однооконные приложения а-ля одностраничное в вебе, но даже если расмотреть вашу ситуацию, то я бы в xaml сделал кнопку с Click на xaml.cs Close(). Это если не надо ничего передавать или контролировать закрытие. Про интерфейс в такой ситуации не задумывался. >> А как бы вы поступили тогда с конвертером? Предположим есть VM и в ней свойство - enum(success, processing, error). V в зависимости от свойства должна то показывать, то не показывать какой-то контрол. Если я делаю EnumToVisConverter и передаю в него параметр - enum.Success, то я нарушаю mvvm, т.к v знает о model?

Comment: @Lapish Я тоже делаю одностраничные приложения, пример закрытия, это лишь пример, где надо через VM закрыть окно, типичная задачка тесной связи VM и M слоев. Я вам дал решение очень базовое, обычно такую задачу делегируют отдельному "сервису", который знает о VM и о V, и по требованию создает их, и управляет ими. `Enum` - начнем с того, что это всеж не VM, да и не M наверно, это ближе к интерфейсам наверно, хотя в разных проектах к ним относятся по разному. А так, эта задача решается без конвертора, при помощи триггеров, чистый XAML.

Comment: Вообще, я вам советую в такие тонкости не лезть, пишите проект так, как вам удобней, просто старайтесь делать так, чтобы V слой жил спокойно без каких либо классов от VM и M, чтобы он о них не знал, вот как я сказал выше, удалите все VM и M классы, запустите проект, если будут ошибки, значит ваш V знает о других слоях, если запустится без данных, то все супер. MVVM это набор рекомендаций, которым все по разному следуют. Я сейчас например использую в проектам WpfUI, в котором автор использует `... ViewModel { get; }` в классе окна (V), это нарушение MVVM, но удобно, я оставил, использую.