# C# WPF Как получить текст с контрола?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вообщем Content - object и может быть разный: ComboBox, TextBlock, TextBox и т.д. можно ли не сравнивая тип каждого получить Text с object? Есть у них какой - небудь общий интерфейс/клас?

Comment: Судя по документации - нет. А почему вы используете вообще контролы? Сделайте нужный вам интерфейс, реализуйте его в нужных классах, привяжите, профит.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я изменяю DataGrid, а именно выравнивание по тексту в DataGridColumnHeader и DataGridCell т.е. мне нужно иметь доступ к событию изменения текста

Comment: И? Это не изменяет тот факт, что работать с контролами плохо. Создаете как я вам и говорил класс, привязываете его и если надо мониторить изменения - прописывайте в свойстве нужную логику, либо INPC, либо привязывайтесь к событию коллекции ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818985/220553)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я изменяю DataGridColumn.Width в зависимости от текста, по моему Это логика именно контрола а не бизнес - логика

Comment: Все зависит от того, что такое, этот ваш "Размер". Если он нужен исключительно для отображения, то его место в View, если же это входные данные (например вам нужна сетка 10 на 10), то это уже логика ViewModel. Например вот [задачка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/220553), как вы вынесите от туда к примеру `Column` и как вы будете потом с этим взаимодействовать? Вам как не крути нужен источник данных, который будет содержать цифру ячейки для отображения.

Comment: Вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста отметьте его принятым.