# Как вызвать обработчик другого класса (внешнего ) в котором имеется List<MyType> При изменении внутреннего поля (MyType.Flag)

Tags: c#, события, property

Вопрос такой могу ли я с помощью INotifyPropertyChanged вызывать обработчик другого класса (в примере TopClass) при  изменении поля OtherClass.Flag именно из самого OtherClass или совсем из  другого

Или же каким либо другим способом но в такой структуре

Если можно было бы  здорово развёрнутый пример)

```
     class TopClass
     {
         private List<OtherClass> _other  { get; set; } 
         public TopClass()
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             {
                _other.Add(new OtherClass());
             }
             _other[0].SomeMethod();// И тут вызывается обработчик
        }

     }
    
     class OtherClass
     {
          public Flag { get; set; } = false;
          public void SomeMethod()
          {
            Flag=!Flag;
          }
     }
```

Comment: У вас нету INPC в примере, о каком тогда событие идет речь? По поводу вопроса, я это описывал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818985/220553), то есть при добавление в коллекцию нового элемента, вам надо подписаться на его событие, а при удаление отписаться. В вашем примере можно изменить эту строку `_other.Add(new OtherClass());` на нечто такое `var item = new OtherClass(); item.SomeEvent += ...; _other.Add(item);`, тем самым вы и добавили и подписались и если `SomeMethod()` вызовет событие `SomeEvent`, то тот, кто подписан на него должен будет выполнить свою логику.

Comment: Спасибо , то  что нужно , всё сделал, отрабатывает отлично.
С ивентами  и  делегатами просто не  очень(

EvgeniyZ очень благодарен !)