# Как при изменении данных datagrid обновлять данные в бд

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

Есть бд подключенных с помощью Entity Framework. Дальше я заношу в DataGrid всю таблицу

```
GridStud.ItemsSource = db.Table.ToList();
```

Я хочу реализовать обновление бд путем изменения данных в DataGrid. Например, меняем значение ячейки в DataGrid и это значение должно обновиться в бд

Comment: Научитесь делать привязки. Сделайте коллекцию `ObservableCollection` (или `BindingList`), привяжите ее к `DataGrid`, далее заносите в нее нужные данные из базы, ну а изменения мониторьте через событие `CollectionChanged` (или аналог).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, так у меня есть datagrid и её столбцы я конкретизирую с помощью Binding="{Binding name}". Я не понимаю как это реализовать :(

Comment: Я ведь вам уже сказал как, привязки, `Binding`. То, что вы делаете `конкретизирую с помощью Binding="{Binding name}"` - это указание столбцов и других данных, а сам `DataGrid` у вас статично в коде получает данные, а должен быть **привязан** к свойству коллекции, в которую вы загружаете данныее.

Comment: Вон вам [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818985/220553) нашел.

Comment: Вот [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567).

Comment: Забью последний гвоздь в крышку гроба этого вопроса: [Entity Framework Core - Начало работы с WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/get-started/wpf).