# Отловить изменение данных в Model из ViewModel ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

У меня в VM есть ObservableCollection c несколькими обьектами. Эта ObservableCollection привязана к ListView и данные там изменяются(например ставиться чек-бокс)

Обьект в ObservableCollection изменяет свое свойство Checked с true на false (или наоборот). На уровне модели Checked это проперти, с триггером OnPropertyChanged()

Мне нужно на уровне ViewModel поймать момент когда пользователь изменяет чекбокс и сделать проверку. Как это можно реализовать не меняя Model?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818985/220553

Comment: Спасибо! кажется это именно то что мне нужно!