# Проблема с обновлением столбца в DataGrid, C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Пишу сейчас тестовый проект на Wpf C# с использованием MVVM. До этого работал с WinForm, поэтому для меня отсутствие обработчиков событий в новинку. Программа должна считать значение функции, типов которой имеется 5 штук. Есть две модели:
Variables:

```
public class Variables : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;
    private double _f;

    public Variables()
    {
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        _f = 0;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get => _x;
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("F");
        }
    }

    public string XChecker
    {
        get => X.ToString();
        set
        {
            int index = value.Length - 1;
            if (index == -1)
            {
                X = 0;
            }
            else if (value[index] >= 48 && value[index] <= 57 && index >= 0)
            {
                X = int.Parse(value);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("VariablesSetsList");
        }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get => _y;
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("F");
        }
    }

    public string YChecker
    {
        get => Y.ToString();
        set
        {
            int index = value.Length - 1;
            if (index == -1)
            {
                Y = 0;
            }
            else if (value[index] >= 48 && value[index] <= 57 && index >= 0)
            {
                Y = int.Parse(value);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVariablesSet");
        }
    }

    public double F
    {
        get => _f;
        set
        {
            _f = value;
            
            OnPropertyChanged("F");
        }
    }

    public void SetF(int a, int b, int c, string funcType)
    {
        int n = 0;
        switch (funcType)
        {
            case "Линейная":
                n = 1;
                break;
            case "Квадратичная":
                n = 2;
                break;
            case "Кубическая":
                n = 3;
                break;
            case "4-ой степени":
                n = 4;
                break;
            case "5-ой степени":
                n = 5;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        _f = (a * Math.Pow(X, n)) + (b * Math.Pow(Y, n - 1)) + c;
        OnPropertyChanged("F");
    }

}
```

И FuncModel:

```
public class FuncTemplate : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _funcType;
    private int _a;
    private int _b;
    private List<int> _c;
    private int _currentC;
    private ObservableCollection<Variables> _variablesSetsList;
    private Variables _currentVariablesSet;

    public FuncTemplate(string funcType)
    {
        _funcType = funcType;
        C = new List<int>();
        _variablesSetsList = new ObservableCollection<Variables>();
        _currentVariablesSet = new Variables();
    }

    public string FuncType
    {
        get => _funcType;
        set
        {
            _funcType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FuncType");
        }
    }

    public int A
    {
        get => _a;
        set
        {
            _a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("A");
        }
    }

    public string AChecker
    {
        get => A.ToString();
        set
        {
            int index = value.Length - 1;
            if (index == -1)
            {
                A = 0;
            }
            else if (value[index] >= 48 && value[index] <= 57 && index >= 0)
            {
                A = int.Parse(value);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("A");
        }
    }

    public int B
    {
        get => _b;
        set
        {
            _b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }

    public string BChecker
    {
        get => B.ToString();
        set
        {
            int index = value.Length - 1;
            if (index == -1)
            {
                B = 0;
            }
            else if (value[index] >= 48 && value[index] <= 57 && index >= 0)
            {
                B = int.Parse(value);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }

    public List<int> C
    {
        get => _c;
        set
        {
            switch (FuncType)
            {
                case "Линейная":
                    _c = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                    break;
                case "Квадратичная":
                    _c = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
                    break;
                case "Кубическая":
                    _c = new List<int> { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
                    break;
                case "4-ой степени":
                    _c = new List<int> { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };
                    break;
                case "5-ой степени":
                    _c = new List<int> { 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000 };
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("C");
        }
    }

    public int CurrentC
    {
        get => _currentC;
        set
        {
            _currentC = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentC");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Свойство поля _variablesSetsList, являющегося коллекцией наборов 
    /// значений переменных x, y, f. При установке значения оповещает 
    /// систему об изменении свойства. 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Variables> VariablesSetsList
    {
        get => _variablesSetsList;
        set
        {
            _variablesSetsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VariablesSetsList");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Свойство поля _currentVariablesSet, содержащего выбранный набор переменных.
    /// В сеттере проверяет, существует ли набор, и либо создает его, 
    /// либо устанавливает значения в существующий, после чего оповещает
    /// систему об изменении свойства. 
    /// </summary>
    public Variables CurrentVariablesSet
    {
        get => _currentVariablesSet;
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                _currentVariablesSet = new Variables();
            else
            {
                _currentVariablesSet = value;
                _currentVariablesSet.SetF(A, B, CurrentC, FuncType);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVariablesSet");
        }
    }
}
```

Вторая - шаблон функции, а первая содержит свой набор переменных для каждой функции.

Также есть View:

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="190"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel
        Name="FuncTypesListStackPanel"
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0">
        <Label 
            Content="Тип функции:"
            Name="FuncTypeLabel"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            FontSize="12"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="10,0,10,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox 
            Name="FunctionTypesListBox"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin ="10,0,10,10"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Functions}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentFunction}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=FuncType}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel
        Name="CurrentFuncFactorsStackPanel"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        DataContext="{Binding CurrentFunction}">

        <Label
            Content="A:"
            Name="FactorALabel"
            FontSize="12"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="FactorATexBox"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="10,0,150,0"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
            FontSize="12"
            Text="{Binding AChecker, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Label 
            Content="B:"
            Name="FactorBLabel"
            FontSize="12"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="FactorBTexBox"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="10,2,150,2"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="12"
            Text="{Binding BChecker, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Label 
            Content="C"
            Name="FactorCLabel"
            FontSize="12"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"/>

        <ComboBox
            Name="FactorCComboBox"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="10,2,150,2"
            FontSize="12"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
            ItemsSource="{Binding C}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentC}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer 
        Name="TableScrollViewer"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        DataContext="{Binding CurrentFunction}"
        >
        <DataGrid 
            Name="TableDataGrid"
            ColumnHeaderHeight="25"
            CanUserAddRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding VariablesSetsList}"
            SelectedItem ="{Binding CurrentVariablesSet}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="x"
                                    Binding="{Binding XChecker, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="y"
                                    Binding="{Binding YChecker, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="f(x,y)"
                                    IsReadOnly = "True"  
                                    Binding="{Binding F}" 
                                    Width="*">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Т.е. последний DataGrid представляет собой таблицу значений для X, Y, F. F должна высчитываться автоматически, сам столбец доступен только на чтение. И я не могу понять, как его таким сделать? Пробовал функцию подсчёта прописать в сеттер выбранного набора переменных, но тогда значение F меняется только при перещелкивании с на другую строку таблицы и обратно. в сеттер F прописать её не могу, так как оттуда нет доступа к коэффициентом A,B,C и типу функции. Подскажите, что можно с этим сделать? Может, я как-то неправильно использую Binding? Уже две недели не могу решить эту проблему.

Comment: У вас, как по мне, есть существенный просчет в архитектуре проекта. Внимание на класс `Variables`, для начала вы его назвали "Переменные", то есть это некий **список** различных переменных. Далее смотрим на `X` и на `Y`, видим, что они идентичны, как в плане "чекера", так и в плане переменной. Аналогично кстати и у класса `FuncTemplate`. Все это сводится к тому, что вам надо сделать класс, который будет отвечать за **одну** переменную, и заполнить далее простую коллекцию ими, ну а дальше, можно сделать уже [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818985/220553).

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог комментарий и оставленная ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю попробовать следующее. Используйте для класса

public class Variables

следующего предка:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

#region -- Общие типы данных
/// <summary>
/// Базовый класс одной записи, реализующий необходимый функционал оповещения о произведённых изменениях. Класс не содержит никаких полей.
/// </summary>
public class myRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Рассылка оповещения о внесении изменения в данные. В качестве параметра (если он не задан принудительно)
    /// автоматически подставляется имя свойства, откуда происходит вызов.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    public void Notify([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
#endregion
```

далее в каждом сеттере просто пишите в конце (код примера взят у Вас):

```
public int X
{
    get => _x;
    set
    {
        _x = value;
        //-- **НЕ ТАК** OnPropertyChanged("F"); 
        Notify(); //<<<< для обновления текущего поля
        //-- Если при установке значения нужно обновить еще несколько полей, то добавляем для каждого:
        Notify("_имя поля_");
        //-- ... а ещё лучше делать так:
        Notify(nameof(имя_класса.имя_поля));
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня подобным образом реализовано, отдельно вынесена в класс реализация INotifyPropertyChanged, и от него наследуются классы. Но я не понимаю, где реализовать функцию подсчёта так, чтобы после изменения поля X или Y на форме сразу подставлялось значение в столбец F. Еще немного не понял момент с 'Notify()' вместо 'OnProperyChanged()', это же просто название метода...

Comment: я же сказал. В сеттере для X пиши (с учетом моего кода) Notify() - это изменения для x и сразу следом -  Notify(nameof(F))  то есть при изменении Х пошлется сразу 2 сигнала, 1-й об изменении X, второй - об изменении F. И Поле в таблице обновится ридером F, Что касаемо OnProp... Как у Вас - обратите внимание на мой класс - PropertyChanged?.Invoke  генерирует сообщение об изменениях если событию назначен хоть один обработчик